# python reading byte by byte from bin file takes too long

Tags: python, binary, byte, bin

i am trying to read the bytes from a bin file with the following code:

```
with open("filedata.bin","rb") as file:
   data = file.read()
   for byte in data:
         print byte
```

this works fine but the issue is that it takes too long (about 4 minutes). The goal is to read any byte of the bin file and send them over a serial interface.

My file is 101 kByte. Until now i didn't send any data over the serial interface. So this can not be the problem. I verify the rate over the python shell with the "print byte". It prints me the first byte to the last byte.

Does someone has an idea how i could read the bytes more quickly?

Comment: what is the size of the file you are trying to read? 4 minutes is a long time for file read...

Comment: Is this all your application does? Or are you doing things with the bytes that you haven't shown here?

Comment: At the moment it is all the stuff i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

when using `file.read()` without any arguments, you read the entire file into memory at once. This is often slow.

To speed this up, you will want to read the file a few bytes at a time.

You can do this is by specifying how many bytes you want to read, for example:

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte:
        # do something with the byte
        byte = f.read(1)
```

A more advanced method to do this is to use the `iter` function:

```
for i in iter(lambda x: f.read(1), b""):
    # do something with the byte
```

Comment: This could be even slower, because it has to do so many I/O operations. It usually is better to use a size closer to the disk block size, maybe 4096 (4kb).

Comment: @Ralf note that the result of `open` is a `BufferedIOBase`, which as the name implies, is buffered. This means it will actually read more than 1 byte from the underlying file, and thus not increase the number of I/O operations. On my machine, it reads 8196 bytes. You can verify this with e.g. `strace`

Comment: @FaridPeymanMohammedZoghian have you verified that reading the file is actually what is slow? How large is your file? It seems more likely to me that the serial is the limit.